# Use the tables in Pbix file into Alteryx

Tags: powerbi, alteryx

I have a Pbix file in my c drive.  I need to use the tables in the pbix in Alteryx.  Please help me locate the ideal connection to use for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’m fairly sure you can’t read the data model within the pbix file outside of e.g. opening it with Power BI.

If it’s a one time thing you can always open the file in Power BI and manually copy or export the data using for example table visualizations, but you can’t programmatically extract the data from the file itself.

If you have access to the dataset as published in Power BI service you can perhaps leverage the fairly new querying API as well to create a workflow for pulling data into Alteryx.